# Best Way to Hide/Show Multiple Surfaces with RenderControllers

Tags: javascript, famo.us, surface

What's the best practice to show/hide multiple surfaces simultaneously? Do I group all the surfaces under one render controller? Or, does each surface have a render controller assigned to it?

I am currently doing the latter, but am left with the distinct difficulty of attempting to  trigger follow-up transitions. This is hard for me because my implementation doesn't provide a clear indication of when all the surfaces have been hidden. It is even harder because the hide transition is triggered with a bounded random time interval (between 200 to 2000 millisecond).

Any solutions? Code below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < surfaces.length; i += 1) {
  var surface = surfaces[i][0];
  var renderController = surfaces[i][1];

  if (s.id !== clickedSurface.id) {
    var fn = (function (s, rc) { 
      return function () { Timer.setTimeout(function () {rc.hide()}, getRandomArbitrary(200,2000)); };
    })(surface, renderController);

    s.colored ? Timer.setTimeout(fn, 2500) : fn();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to iterate through your surfaces and hide one at a time, you could do something like the following code shows.

**[Example jsBin Here](http://jsbin.com/xiyozi/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  function _hideNext(index) {
    if (index === surfaces.length) {
      //do something final, now complete
      _showNext(0);
    } else {
      var rc = surfaces[index][1];
      var surface = surfaces[index][0];
      var nextIndex = index + 1;
      rc.hide(surface, _hideNext.bind(this, nextIndex));
    }
  }

  _hideNext(0);
```

Just change your `RenderController` options to your needs.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up. :) I made wunder-hexagons.herokuapp.net with your advice.

Comment: I just saw it the other day.  It looks great too!  Glad I was of some help. Looking forward to seeing mixed mode released.  Hope it goes open source.

Comment: **[Here is your corrected link http://wunder-hexagons.herokuapp.com/](http://wunder-hexagons.herokuapp.com/)**